# How to access outer border elements of a two dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Suppose an array x[3][3] with elements as

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How to access the outer border elemens of x as 1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,1 ? I am able to come up with some patterns for this problem but having difficultly converting it into loops. We need to keep row constant and increase column no. and then column no. constant and increase row no. Then after we need to keep row no. constant and decrease column no. to 0 and at last keep column no. constant to decrease row no. back to 0.

Comment: Four loops would be the best (optimal) approach, IMO. Just as you already described. Otherwise, you can do a single loop and control what increases (line or column) with IFs, but that wouldn't be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this is by keeping a pair of "coordinate" variables `r` for row and `c` for column, and a pair of "delta" variables `dr` for changing the row for the next step and `dc` for changing the column for the next step.

Here are the valid combinations for `dr` and `dc:

```
dr dc direction
-- -- ---------
 0  1 Right
 1  0 Down
 0 -1 Left
-1  0 Up
```

Start `dr` at zero, and `dc` at `1` for "moving right". On each iteration of the loop you add `dr` to `r`, and `dc` to `c`. After that you check if you need to "turn" right.

The trick to turning right is in the following three lines of code:

```
int tmp = dr;
dr = dc;
dc = -tmp;
```

To make sure that it works try it out on the four combinations above. You will see that it changes the pair `(dr, dc)` in the sequence right-down-left-up-right... and so on.

Execute this code each time when you reach a corner to complete the program.

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing what dasblinkenlight suggested and got it to work. Here is the code.

```
printf("\nOuter border of the array: ");

int dr = 0;
int dc = 1;
int r = 0;
int c = 0;
int count = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){

    printf("%d ", x[r][c]);

    if (count == 2){

        int tmp = dr;
        dr = dc;
        dc = -tmp;
        count = 1;
    }
    else{
        count++;
    }

    r = r + dr;
    c = c + dc;
}

}
```